# Twitter Typeahead match anything from token

Tags: typeahead.js

i was wondering if typeahead can match anything from input

if i have JSON with tokens['asdf','asd','sdfg','dfgh']

so if I type sd would mactch all containing string with minimum 2 characters for example.

If it cannot be implemented so easily maybe i can use some other plugin to get such functions.

Comment: Ok so i managed to get it to work. Little reverse engeneering and i found out that there is a function if not giving  any tokens it makes array of every word in value.
i added another function that pushes to deafult tokens additional values from datum. Now hardcoded to my values but i think i will rewrite it to universal.

Comment: can you write down your solution here please?